# Setting an instance property to a static property

Tags: c#

I'm sorry if the title's a bit unusual or wrong, I'm not certain about how to ask this. Please offer an edit or change it if so.

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
private class Products
{
    public Status 
    { 
        // set status to `Active`, `Deleted` or `Suspended` for an instance of Products. // 
    }
}
```

What I don't know how to do is code something that will allow me to call `Products.Status.Active`, then set that value to `MyAccount`. The other two values will be `Suspended` and `Deleted`.

Comment: Is `TaskClass.Status` an enum? I'm not sure if I got your problem...

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You are calling a private instance method, statically. Perhaps if you pseudo code what you are looking for we can adapt that into something workable.

Comment: Why are you trying to set a static class property? If you do this all instances of Account will contain the same status. Can you clear up your question a bit?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I have to admit that I have no idea what I'm talking about here. I'm looking to be able to set the `Status` to one of three things: `Active`, `Suspended` or `Deleted`. Maybe it's a property of the `TaskClass` method, but I really don't know. For instance, take 
    `HttpRequestCachePolicy noCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);` as an example.

Comment: ...yes this is my code. I'm very sorry if it's hard to read. I'm struggling to write down what I want.

Comment: @NickBull  The reason I ask is because judging by your own comments, such as `"Maybe it's a property of the TaskClass method, but I really don't know."` you don't seem to even understand how your own code works.

Comment: I understand to a degree, I'm just not sure how to create code that I can call with `TaskClass.Status.Active`, instead of setting the property to a string.

Comment: @NickBull what is `TaskClass.Status.Active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make Status an enum

```
public enum Status
{
    Active = 1,
    Suspended = 2,
    Deleted = 3
}
```

Looks like you want to implement ChangeStatus as static

```
public class TaskClass
{
    public static ChangeStatus(Accounts.Account a, MyTask t, Status s)
    {...}
}

private void Main() {
    Accounts.Account account = new Accounts.Account();
    TaskClass.Task task = new TaskClass.Task();

    TaskClass.ChangeStatus(account, task, Status.Active);
}
```

PS If you need to name it TaskClass.Status instead of Status, just nest the enum inside TaskClass.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Apologies about how poor the question is, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @NickBull The problem with your question is that you're trying to use **very specific** functionality that you don't even seem to know about, and you're not telling us what you're using it for.

Comment: I know that now, and I've edited the question so it's easier for people to understand if anybody stumbles across this question in search of an answer to a similar problem. Only learned about the real power of properties today! Apologies for the poorly asked question

Comment: @NickBull the problem with your question isn't in what you told us.  rather, it's what you didn't tell us:  What is the actual(real-world) problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to understand where the problem lies in how I asked this question. Writing code I don't understand myself isn't going to lead others to understand. I wanted a class to have a property that could be set or gotten, that could have three dynamic values; Active, Suspended or Deleted. This is not production code - it's for my own understanding, so there's no purpose. I'm not new to C#, but neither have I learnt it from a book, nor have I been taught. It's left big gaps in my understanding of it. This is something I've wanted to know for a while.